# Where to find updated best practice on using unmaintained or legacy software on a patched OS?

Tags: account-security, operating-systems, software

I assume most of the security issues with old software are

- that scripts or .exe will run against the bugs in the software.
- and that the firmware on the device OS bugs aren't patched.
- Or some parts of the machine are accessible to the internet so can be remotely hacked?
- Or when opening downloaded files from trusted or untrusted sources you get malware from them that targets the bugs/unpatched areas?

#### Assuming one patches:

- OS
- Firewall
- Internet-facing parts
- Hopefully Firmware (hard for old hardware?)

**Where can you look for best practices on what to do next when using legacy software?**

I ask as many businesses have legacy software and hardware and struggle to switch on cost, useability.

This is not meant to be a "write a book" answer as I have asked for other good sites where this might be answered in some detail instead?

I realise this will change over time hence why other sources that update will be better?

Comment: Add comment about #legacy or some other relevant tags

Comment: @Rohit-Gupta Thanks, I tried to get the formatting right.  Any ideas of better tags to use?

Comment: @user187989 Thanks, tried to get the formating right but any ideas on better tags?

Comment: I couldnt find any other relevant tags.  I don't have enough rep to create new tags.

Comment: It can be argued that these businesses can't afford NOT to update the software.  There is no short or long answer here... you just want to research what vulnerabilities each piece of software might have... this might be difficult if the software company is out of business, but you could certainly ask them if they are still around... at which point they'll try to sell you an up-to-date version.

Comment: @pcalkins Fair point, but a bit depressing, I figure we need solutions to that, as that everyone interested in security?

Comment: @RohitGupta Ah ok, thank you